# How to get data from one table based on a data from another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, webmethod

I have a two tables

```
 tblstudent (StudentID (PK), StudentNumber, Name & Surname)
```

and

```
 tblfingerprint (ID (PK), StudentID (FK), Template)
```

I have a web service that selects a Template based on their ID. However, I want to be able to select the template from `tblFingerprint` based on the given `StudentNumber` and not `StudentID` in  `tblStudent`.

I have the following code so far. I'm not sure if I need to use `leftjoin or innerjoin?`

```
[WebMethod]
public Verification StuVerification(Student student)
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Template FROM tblFingerprint WHERE  ID = '"+ student.StudentNumber + "'", cn);

    //SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Template FROM tblFingerprint WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'", cn);
    //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Template", Template);
    SqlDataReader sr = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (sr.Read())
    {
        Verification verification = new Verification()
        {
            StudentID = sr.GetInt32(0),
            StudentNumber = sr.GetString(1),
            Name = sr.GetString(2),
            Surname = sr.GetString(3),
        };
        cn.Close();
        return verification;

    }

    cn.Close();
    return new Verification();

}
```

Comment: when not sure then use left join .

Comment: I would use inner join if i only want students who have a template, but if you want to know when a student doesn't have template use left joun. but is ID in the fingerprint table the same as StudentNumber in the student table?

Comment: If every student is guaranteed to have a Student Number, use an inner join.  If you want results regardless of whether the student has a student number or not use a left join.

Comment: why you are using the inline queries... your code is not secure if you are using inline queries.. try to use Stored procedures everytime

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner join between the two tables, but as usual use a parameterized query

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT s.StudentID, s.StudentNumber, s.Name, s.Surname, f.Template 
                   FROM tblStudent s INNER JOIN tblFingerprint f
                   ON t.StudentID = f.StudentID 
                   WHERE s.StudentNumber = @numb";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numb", student.StudentNumber);
```

In an INNER JOIN only the records of the first table that have corresponding records on the second table are returned (in your case only the students that have a corresponding record in the tblFingerprint table)
In a LEFT JOIN every records of the first table are returned with the corresponding values of the second table. If any student has no record in the tblFingerprint, the Template field will be null

Also, note that you try to read 4 fields from your datareader, but the actual query contains just the Template field. Thus I have added the missing fields to your query

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you did a little search for yourself you would find thousands of pages with information about it.

OT: you can join the table

```
SELECT Template FROM tblFingerprint WHERE ID = '"+ student.StudentNumber + "'


SELECT Template 
FROM tblFingerprint F
INNER JOIN tblStudent S
ON F.StudentID = S.StudentID
WHERE S.StudentNumber = '"+ student.StudentNumber + "'"
```

Hint: Work with parameters, in this example there a major risk for SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is equivalent to INNER JOIN on SQL Server so just use the following. I've added aliases to the table names to make it less verbose.

I've based it on your example so I have to assume that StudentNumber is a string field. If not then just remove the string delimiters from your query.

```
"SELECT Template FROM tblFingerprint fp 
JOIN tblstudent s ON fp.StudentID = s.StudentID
WHERE s.StudentNumber = '"+ student.StudentNumber + "'"
```

Hope this helps.
Al.

Comment: JOIN is not equivalent to LEFT JOIN in SQL Server.  JOIN is equivalent to INNER JOIN.